# About 8086 Microprocessor Memory

Tags: microprocessors

It is said that 8086 Microprocessor has 1MB Memory  and 20-bit address, 16- bit data bus . My doubt is that if it is 1MB memory that means (2^20 * 2^3) (1 byte = 8 bits) bits or 2^ 23 bits is the whole memory size. Then as 8086 is a 16- bit register then 2^20 ( from address lines) * 2^4( 16- bit size) is the memory i.e 2^ 24 bits which is not  what I calculated above.
So there is a false in my assessment , what is that ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the 2^20 addresses refers to an 8-bit Byte.

Some of the 8086's machine instructions operate on Bytes (8-bits) (using registers AH, AL, BH, BL, ...) and other machine instructions operate on Words (16-bits) (using registers AX, BX, ...).

When using a Word instruction, two adjacent bytes in memory (addresses (a) and (a+1)) are treated as a Word datum. I do not recall if the 8086 enforces even address alignment for Word-datum memory references. But, 2^20 Bytes contains only 2^19 Words (aligned to even addresses).

Bits are conserved:
(2^20 * 2^3) = (2^19 * 2^4) = 2^23